# In Snowflake, how can i format the numbers with "M" and "B" suffix for Millions and Billions

Tags: sql, numbers, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, suffix

In Snowflake, how can i format the numbers with "M" and "B" suffix for Millions and Billions
like display the number as 10**M** instead of 10,000,000

and 10**B** instead of 10,000,000,000

i tried formatting the numbers, but couldn't not achieve as desired.

Comment: What is the range of possible values for the numbers?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: this will be applicable for all numbers..  no specific range..

Comment: How should 10,500,123 be displayed?

Comment: unless you are rounding/truncating to "larger grain" for some form of grouping, it sounds like you are doing presentation logic in a database, which is the wrong layer. you number is just a number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: that should be seen as 10M

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim: you are absolutely right, however, i am exploring options on the database layer if it is possible, because not all datasets have a presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

These examples should show you how to achieve what you want:

```
select to_char(round(10000000/1000000,0))||'M'; -- 10M

select to_char(round(12314578/1000000, 2))||'M'; -- 12.31M
```